# Arduino Standalone

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, atmega, arduino-ide

I have an Arduino Uno and I am using arduino 1.0.5 IDE. I followed he [procedures for bootloading an atmega328P-PU on a breadboard](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard).

I uploaded the ArduinoISP sketch first, made the connections(using the External Oscillator) and then wired it up. Then, I selected the programmer as Arduino as ISP, selected the board as Arduino duemilanove w/ Atmega328P. Then I selected the correct serial port and clicked Burn Bootloader. 
I got the following errors:

> avrdude.exe: stk500_program_enable(): protocol error, expect=0x14,
>   resp=0x50avrdude.exe: initialization failed, rc=-1              Double
>   check connections and try again, or use -F to override
>   this check.avrdude.exe: stk500_disable(): protocol error, expect=0x14,
>   resp=0x51

How to solve this issue? Also, can I upload the bootloader directly by using it on the Uno in place of the original chip. If so, how?

Comment: This question is probably more suited for [Arduino StackExchange](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/) - it could potentially be a hardware problem

Answer (score 1):

to my understanding the error you have indicates a bad reading from the chip. I experienced that with chips that were either dead or not properly connected, especially to power supply.

You may find more detailed information in th tutorial : https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP

Especially those things :

- Note for Arduino 1.0: you need to make one small change to the
  ArduinoISP code. Find the line in the heartbeat() function that says
  "delay(40);" and change it to "delay(20);".
- Select the items in the
  Tools > Board and Serial Port menus that correspond to **the board you
  are using as the programmer** (not the board being programmed).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of arduino built-in boot loader just go through below link and it will be great for uploading boot loader and verifying board status info

I am replying you this because same issue I got long back and it saved me.

One more thing for arduino boot loader: for atmega328 you need to put capacitor between reset and gnd( in case you missed)

For gammon bootloader you don't need it.

---

Be Innovative.

Answer (score 0):

For reset line you might me using 100nf(thats what stated in documentation )...but sometimes it doesn't work...try something like 4.7uf, 22uf or 47uf or close values

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the issue was that my programmer was a bit slow, I used the -B flag for avrdude to slow down the bitrate and it started working, I set the -B20 and works like a charm every time, but I use the USBTinyISP programmer, not the stk500 one, so this might not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone stuck at this as I did and nothing like changing the cap value helped. Make sure you are using your USB-TTL adapter in a 5v mode (obviously for a 5v powered chip). I always used it in a 3.3v mode in order not to accidentally burn my 3.3v chips and it always worked. Until today, I was trying to flash my custom atmega8 board and everything worked with the ISP but I was having a hard time using the bootloader and after half a day searching and trying different stuff the 5v setting to the rescue.